# Dynamic Value Dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have variabled called `types` that I want to display in the select dropdown. I have a difficulty displaying it. Its values are dynamic based on the `types`.
Pls check my codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-select-dropdown-styled-components-wqhxk?file=/Main.js)

**Code**

```
 {types.map((value, index) => (
        <Dropdown value={value} index={index} />
 ))}


const Dropdown = ({ value, index }) => {
  const select = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };
  return (
    <Select onChange={(e) => select(e)}>
      {/* {value.map((value, index) => (
        {value.name}
        <option value="1">{value.option[index+1]}</option>
      ))} */}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<Dropdown />` component the value is not an array but an object. If you want to loop over it, do the following:

```
    const Dropdown = ({ value, index }) => {
  const select = (e, value) => {
    console.log("event", e);
    console.log("object", value);
  };
  return (
    <Select onChange={(e) => select(e, value)}>
      {Object.keys(value)
        .filter((key) => value[key] && key.startsWith("option"))
        .map((key, index) => (
          <option value={key}>{value[key]}</option>
        ))}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-select-dropdown-styled-components-forked-78qm6?file=/Dropdown.js

Comment: Hi, it should display the value of the options like 6 Pack, red, blue etc...

Comment: @Joseph, you just had to swap the key/value like ``<option value={key}>{value[key]}</option>``. I updated my answer and codesandbox

Comment: Thanks. any idea how not to display the `null values` and also console.log the whole object selected in `select` function.

Comment: @Joseph, to remove null value just added additional check in the filter function ``value[key] && key.startsWith("option")``. To display the selected object I had to pass it to the select function. Updated my answer and sandbox

Comment: @Joseph, forgot to update the sandbox URL in the prev edit https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-select-dropdown-styled-components-forked-78qm6?file=/Dropdown.js

Comment: Thank you. How about you console.log the values already selected since dropdown already prefilled when the page loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235166/discussion-between-nedko-dimitrov-and-joseph).

Comment: Hi again. how can i remove the prefilled values in dropdown when page loads? its already prefilled, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using your data structure, your `Dropdown` component works if you do it this way but would only pick the first option.

```
const Dropdown = ({ value, index }) => {
  return (
    <Select>
        <option value="1">{value[`option${index+1}`]}</option>
    </Select>
  );
};
```

But this is what I advise, If this is within your control, I would advise you restructure your `types` data structure a little bit to something like below

```
const types = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "color",
      options: [
        {value: "red", label: "red"}, 
        {value: "blue", label: "blue"}
      ],
      price: 12
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "weight",
      options: [
        {value: "", label: "Placeholder"},
        {value: "20", label: "20 Kilos"}, 
        {value: "30", label: "30 Kilos"}, 
        {value: "40", label: "40 Kilos"}, 
        {value: "50", label: "50 Kilos"}
      ],
      price: 13
    }
];
```

Then your dropdown component can also be refactored to this

```
const Dropdown = ({ options, index }) => {
  return (
    <Select>
      {options.map((option) => <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>)}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

This would enable you to easily use your `Dropdown` component with the `type` array as follows

```
  return (
    <MainContainer>
      {types.map((value, index) => (
        <Dropdown options={value.options} index={index} />
      ))}
    </MainContainer>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to fix the type structure, anyway you can fix it in js side by following code

```js
let options = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(value).filter(entry => Object.keys(value).filter(k => k.startsWith("option")).includes(entry[0])));
```

sample options value:

```js
{option1: "20 Kilo", option2: "30 Kilo", option3: "40 Kilo", option4: "50 Kilo"}
```